# Dynamically add arrays in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to add new arrays to an existing array dynamically from a database but my loop is only adding the last row from mysql_fetch_row. I think it is actually overwriting the same array.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$con = require_once('./dbconnect.php');

global $con;
mysql_select_db("packages", $con);
$packages = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM packages");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($packages)){
    $node = array();

    foreach($row as $key2 => $value2){
        $node[$row[0]] = array("Item1" => "Other dynamic Info here");
    }
}

print_r($node);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [Pack1] => Array
        (
            [Item1] => Other dynamic Info here
        )

)
```

It should be outputting:

```
Array
(
    [Pack1] => Array
        (
            [Item1] => Other dynamic Info here
        )

)
Array
(
    [Pack2] => Array
        (
            [Item2] => Other dynamic Info here
        )

)
```

**I have been trying to get this foreach() loop to work for about a day now...what am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Well, you are overwriting $node = array() each time in the while loop. It will contain a single result after the while is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare

```
$node = array();
```

outside the while loop.

If indexing of the node array is irrelevant you can just use the "append" notation

```
foreach($row as $key2 => $value2){
    node[] = array("Item1" => "Other dynamic Info here");
}
```

Comment: $node[] without value  ? $node[counter?]

Answer (score 1):

**Try To define the $node array outside the while loop as:**

```
$node = array(); ## <-- HERE

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($packages))
{    
    foreach ($row as $key2 => $value2) 
    {
        $array      = array("Item1" => "Other dynamic Info here");
        $key        = $row[0];
        $node[$key] = $array;
    }
}
```

You can also use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) to debug your code, so you find out more quickly when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
foreach($row as $key2 => $value2){
    $node[$key2] = array("Item1" => "Other dynamic Info here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the array on each cycle through the `while` loop, but only outputting the array once after the last cycle. Your code should be like the following (notice the position of `print_r`):

```
<?php
$con = require_once('./dbconnect.php');

global $con;
mysql_select_db("packages", $con);
$packages = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM packages");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($packages)){
    $node = array();

    foreach($row as $key2 => $value2){
        $node[$row[0]] = array("Item1" => "Other dynamic Info here");
    }
    print_r($node);
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

That will output the array on each cycle through the `while` loop.